# Do any Apple Products Support HDCP 2.2?

Tags: macbook-pro, hdcp

I've found a few questions on here that are several years old and ask about general HDCP support.  However, with the oncoming 4k revolution a new version of the specification, HDCP 2.2, has been introduced specifically to lock down 4k content.

For instance, in order to stream Netflix at UHD quality, your display (and cables/connections) must support HDCP 2.2.

From the [Netflix UHD Help Page](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/13444):

> Please note that both the HDMI cable and the HDMI port on your TV must be HDCP 2.2 certified.

I'm having a hard time finding any hard facts on this.

Mostly I'm curious about my current device, a 15" Mid 2014 MBP with an Nvidia GT 750M and retina display.